# Add a decimal after two first numbers

Tags: php

I am generating some data of latitude and longitude with `rand(10000000, 3000000);` for example. But I need to calculate distance between two locations, so basically I need to convert my result, for example `22049256` to `22.049256` in order to pass to my function.

How can I achieve this most effectively with using least amount of resources?

TL;DR
I have integer `22049256`, needs to be converted to float `22.049256`.

Comment: Your min value is greater than the max value. typo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide by 1M?

`22049256 / 1000000 = 22.049256`

Comment: This would be fine just remember the result would be a float if you are explicitly declaring the variables.

Comment: Thanks, stupid of me to now figure this out by myself. But than again I'm not that bright at all :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

```
$foo = rand(10000000, 30000000);
$foo /= 1000000;
echo $foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the decimal after the first two digits, that should do the trick.

```
<?php
    $n = rand(10000000, 3000000);
    $len = strlen($n);
    $div = pow(10, $len - 2);
    $n /= $div;
    var_dump($n);
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Nrql15

Basically just dividing by a number made by checking how many characters there are in your original number.

Answer (score -2):

Simplest way would be to treat the number as a string and iterate through it, adding the decimal point at the appropriate position.

```
$new_number = '';
for($i=0;$i<strlen((string)$number;$i++)
{
    if($i == 2)
        $new_number .= '.';
    $new_number .= substr((string)$number, $i, 1);
}
```

Edit:

Another possibility is to divide by 1000000 and run number_format to ensure proper decimal places:

```
$new_number = number_format($number/1000000, 6);
```